# 'Different results for the same function called from SQL Developer UI and in SQL query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

`F` is a function counting the number of weekdays betwwen two dates (using the format `to_date(a, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` [NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = "FRENCH"]. 
It is stored in package `P`.

With `a` is the beginning date of the period and `b` the end.

When I use the SQL developer to run the function i.e. Right click on package `p`, execute, choose `f` function and fill the arguments:

```
if a = to_date('02/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and b = to_date('12/08/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

**I get a number of days =  7, which is the correct result.**

But when I run it in SQL:

```sql
select p.f('02/08/2019','12/08/2019') from DUAL
```

**I get a number of days = 8 and this result is obviously wrong.**

I cannot understand how these two process can return two different values since the same `F` function is called, and the arguments are exactly the same.

I have been careful about the date format, still **the two ways of calling `f` won't return the same result**.

For information, this is the content of this function (sorry, cariable are expressed in french)

```
FUNCTION getjoursouvres
(
    i_debut IN DATE,
    i_fin IN DATE   
)
RETURN NUMBER IS o_result NUMBER;
v_jour date;
v_nbjours NUMBER;
v_testferie number;
v_testweekend number;
v_testglobal number;
-- This cursor browses all dates between i_debut and i_fin (included)
cursor cx is 
            select to_date(i_debut, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + rownum -1 dt 
            from dual 
            connect by level <= to_date(i_fin, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date(i_debut, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1;
BEGIN
open cx;
v_nbjours := 0;
    loop
-- Browses all the days in the interval (begining and end included)
        fetch cx into v_jour;
        exit when cx%NOTFOUND;
-- testferie return 1 if the day is NOT a holiday, 0 if it is (so not be be added)
            v_testferie := testferie(v_jour);
-- testweekend return 1 if the day is a weekday, 0 if it is on weekend (so not be be 
            v_testweekend := testweekend(v_jour);
-- 
            v_testglobal := v_testferie + v_testweekend;
-- If v_testglobal = 2 then the day is neither weekend nor holiday. Therefore it is aded to the sum of days
            if v_test = 2 then
                v_nbjours := v_nbjours + 1;
            end if;
    end loop;
o_result := v_nbjours;
close cx;
return o_result;
END;
```

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the contents of your function `f`.

Comment: `select f.p(a,b) from DUAL` - what are `a` and `b` in that case?

Answer (score 1):

After many calls of both way to use the function. I reach to the conclusion that the element inducing the anomaly comes from the ue of

```
to_date(v_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

where v_date is already declared as a date format behave in an inpredictable way.
I decided to keep the date variable as such, and only use to_date for different cariable format.

I am not able to explain why exactly, but it solved my problems concerning dates behavior. Now I can call a function with data parameter from DUAL or from the SQL developer interface and get identical and coherent results.

Comment: *"where v_date is already declared as a date format"* Did you mean declared as a **date**? A date doesn’t have any format.